# How to check when is the last time a row is selected in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql

Literally as the title said.

I'm checking an old database left by earlier developer, and apparently instead of creating a new "Master" table, he created a table which contains constants in the form of JSONs. Now however I want to check whether that row is still used, and when is the last time it's used.

When transitioning, the developer doesn't provide documentation whatsoever. So I have to check on my own on how things should work. I want to know because **the code is really messy.** Also since I can't seem to find this on Google, it's something worth to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You cannot log past events.** PostgreSQL does not retain that information.

The best you can do is:

1. Set `log_statement = 'all'`
2. Examine the statements in the log.

Comment: Does this configuration can be used to check past events? Or is it only once the `log_statement` is set with the new variable?

Comment: You cannot log past events. PostgreSQL does not retain that information.

Comment: Now, that's the answer I need! I'm thankful for your answer, it's great that you are knowledgeable about PostgreSQL but I think you can improve it by adding a little explanation to it. Things like what I just asked, so I know there's no other option than trying that. Now I can understood that your answer is the best option! Nonetheless, thanks again!